# Tables in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I have tables which I want to set horizontally, they are too big that they don't fit with the page, either column header shift down, are doesn't fit on page, how can set them. I used long table too. What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-size the table to make it fit the page size. Like this:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{table}
...
\scalebox{0.7}{   %% change it to smaller here, change to other values if needed
    \begin{tabular}
    ...
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```